# Replacing deprecated ereg_replace() with preg_replace() did not work

Tags: php, deprecated

The following PHP program replaces the symbols !£$%^& with nulls

```
 <?php

 $string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£$%^&";
 $new_string = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]", "", $string);
 echo "Old string is: ".$string."<br />New string is: ".$new_string;

 ?>
```

Output:

Old string is: This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£$%^&
New string is: This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols

But, I have learned that the function ereg_replace() has been deprecated and that I should use the function preg_replace() instead.  I made the substitution like so:

```
 <?php

 $string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£$%^&";
 $new_string = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]", "", $string);
 echo "Old string is: ".$string."<br />New string is: ".$new_string;

 ?>
```

but got the wrong output:

Old string is: This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£$%^&
New string is: This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !£$%^&

What did I do wrong?  How do I fix it?

Comment: This page explains the differences between POSIX regex (used by ereg_replace) and PCRE regex (used by preg_replace): http://us3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php

Comment: Thanks to @TheOx.  Shortly after posting, I checked the manual and found that I needed to add delimiters to my pattern when using preg_replace().  So, using "/" as my delimiter, the pattern "[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]" becomes "/[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]/".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be missing markers around the regular expression.  Try this instead (note the slashes around the pattern).

```
$string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !$%^&";
$new_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]/", "", $string);
echo "Old string is: ".$string."<br />New string is: ".$new_string;
```

You can use any character for the markers as long as the same one is found on both sides.  Very useful if your pattern is matching `/` characters.  So this is also valid:

```
$string = "This is some text and numbers 12345 and symbols !$%^&";
$new_string = preg_replace("~[^A-Za-z0-9 (),.]~", "", $string);
echo "Old string is: ".$string."<br />New string is: ".$new_string;
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a weird bug that I have experienced as well. for some reason the empty quotes screw up this function but I got it to work by using

```
preg_replace($pattern, NULL, $string);
```

instead of

```
preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Comment: Ehh, which version of PHP are you using? I've never seen this.

Comment: @Brower please see my comment to TheOX above.  I was able to use "" instead of null and it worked properly.  The important thing is the use of delimiters with preg_replace().