# Opencats installation error

Tags: php, linux

[image]I am trying to install opencats. While installing i am getting following error..
What is the problem?

```
Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/opencats/ajax.php on line 86

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/opencats/ajax.php on line 87

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/opencats/ajax.php on line 86

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in /opt/lampp/htdocs/opencats/ajax.php on line 87


Test Results
Antiword binary failed to convert a DOC file to text properly (Should have returned 'This is a test document', returned '').
Pdftotext binary failed to convert a PDF file to text properly (Should have returned 'This is a test document', returned '').
Html2Text binary /usr/bin/html2text does not exist.
UnRTF depends on Html2Text and can not execu
```

Comment: Which version of opencats did you tried to install and what's your PHP version?

Comment: opencats 0.9.and php version is 5.4.17.

Comment: Try 0.9.1a and let me know if it has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

ereg_replace is deprecated. The alternative is preg_replace.

This post seemed to demonstrate it well: [Replacing deprecated ereg_replace() with preg_replace() did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741740/replacing-deprecated-ereg-replace-with-preg-replace-did-not-work)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a critical error, you can suppress these messages by changing display_errors to off in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

The opencats which is working on even php 5.6 can be downloaded from [Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/candidats/files/latest/download?source=files)

**Note**:

CATS development as open source has been stopped at 2008. OpenCATS continued the deveopment. But concentrated on OSATS. So the http://sourceforge.net/projects/candidats are continuing the project from, where CATSONE dropped.